# Literature to Learn about Different Instruments

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, derivatives

What is a good source of literature to learn about the specifics of various instruments that are traded?

For example, suppose I wanted to know more about MBS's, i.e. how exactly they are securitized, how exactly they are tranched, what different types of strategies traders might look at to price the tranches, and how they trade across this asset class. Is there a good book for that? Now, is there a book that does that for several more assets (like currencies, bonds, options, credit swaps, etc.)

Comment: There are such books, and I used to own 1 or 2, but I don't any more because they become obsolete after a few years and they seldom turn out to have the specific detail you need when you need it. Instead it is better to buy in depth books about specific subjects that you are interested in.